# How to create new object in redux selector and return it

Tags: angular, object, redux, selector, new-operator

Is there a way, how to create new object in redux selector and return it? I was searching around the net, but found no answer.

something like this:

```
export interface UserModel {
    user: string,
    job: string,
    contact: string,
    sex: string //not saved in store model
}

 export const mySelector= createSelector(
    moduleState,
    state => {
       state.user,
       state.job,
       state.contact
       } as Partial<UserModel> //casting not possible
  );

store$.select(Selectors.mySelector).subscribe(partialUser => { //partialUser is void
    cons sex = 'M';
    const user = {...partialUser, ...sex} as UserModel //spread operator possible only for objects
    }
```

If there is no such option in selectors, how to create objects from state properties and subscribe to them? My store state model is created from BE DTOs, so I dont need to do the mapping, when getting data from BE, but for FE UI models, I need to create objects derived from interfaces from store state, and I want to aviod manual typing and mapping. (the name of the properties in store state object match with the interfaces). Maybe it is possible with keyof and Partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made errors in your attempts:

1. if you have arrow function that returns object it needs to be in round brackets

```
export const mySelector= createSelector(
  moduleState,
  state => ({
    user: state.user,
    job: state.job,
    contact: state.contact
  } as Partial<UserModel>)
);
```

2. you wanted to spread string instead of just adding `sex` field to `partialUser`

```
store$.select(Selectors.mySelector).subscribe(partialUser => {
  //partialUser is void
  cons sex = 'M';
  const user = { ...partialUser, sex } as UserModel;
}
```

Comment: thx, that worked. I forgot to declare the names of the props in the selector, that was the main issue.